# Newton's third law and Coulomb's law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electrostatics, free-body-diagram, coulombs-law

Coulomb's law states that if we have two charges $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$, then $q_{1}$ will act on $q_{2}$ with a force $$ \textbf{f}_{12}=\frac{q_{1}q_{2}}{r_{12}^2} { \hat {\textbf {r}}_{12}},$$

and $q_{2}$ will similarly act on $q_{1}$ with a force $\textbf{f}_{21}$ such that
$$\,\textbf{f}_{21}=-\textbf{f}_{12}.$$

Suppose the only things we knew was that the repulsive forces vary like $r^{-2}$, and that they depend on the magnitude of the charges involved. Can we infer from these two observations alone that  $\textbf{f}_{21}=-\textbf{f}_{12}$? Or would we need further experiments to establish this equation?

The collinearity can be deduced from symmetrical considerations. What about the magnitude?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Suppose the only things we knew was that the repulsive forces vary like $r^{-2}$, and that they depend on the magnitude of the charges involved. Can we infer from these two observations alone that  $\textbf{f}_{21}=-\textbf{f}_{12}$?

No. In fact, it is not true in general, for a system of two charged particles, that the force acting on charge 1 and the force acting on charge 2 obey Newton's third law at a particular time, given a particular frame of reference. In general there is radiation, Coulomb's law is false, and momentum is exchanged between the charges and the radiation.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth  repeating that **laws** in physics are **axioms**, there is no  proof or derivation other than that the law is necessary, so that a physical mathematical theory can choose those solutions that will **fit existing data** and, important, will be **predictive** in new situations. Laws in effect are a distillate of data.

Coulomb's law defines one of the possible forces, so  that Newton's laws can be used  in order to have classical mechanics solutions and predictability in kinematic  problems involving charges.

Comment: This answer ignores the fact that there are intricate logical interrelationships between various physical laws and principles. They are not purely empirical.

Comment: @BenCrowell  "intricate logical correlations" are usually called "mathematics" even  if between laws established by observations. Of course laws hold for the framework of phase space where they were observed to hold, to start with. Otherwise,  mathematics has to be used by going from a logically lower framework, to an emergent one, including for the laws used.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh  I believe it is. as both are laws necessary for a mathematical model for the data., and consistent in their overlap (kinematics)

Comment: @yuvrajsingh if you tell me which chat room at what time? why not.?

Comment: Either you create an chat room,  because there are chat room available,  but they are only for high standard physics.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh  lets see if this works https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/100103/anna-v?tab=general  . we have to agree on a time. I could spend some time in two hours , unless a problem comes up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100105/discussion-between-yuvraj-singh-and-anna-v).

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. Newton explicitly formulated his theory of gravitation so that it would be consistent with conservation of momentum (Newton's third law). Coulomb did the same 100 years later when he formulated what is now called Coulomb's law.

Yes, Coulumb's law (As well as Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation) do imply Newton's third law of motion. As you can see, it was an integral part of determining that the forces exerted by the particles are equal and opposite.

Conservation of momentum can be proven using elastic collisions

Answer (score -2):

Conservation of momentum requires that the forces be reciprocal. The change in the momentum of charge 1 arising from the force between the charges must create an exactly opposite change in the momentum of charge 2 at all times, so the forces must be equal and opposite.

Comment: This answer was given to the original version of the question- It's not relevant to the edited version.